# Nodal analysis Example

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hru2p.jpg]

Question:Find the Vo voltage using the node voltages method.Thanks in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFoh2.jpg]

I chose the following node as the reference node.I created the equations but i couldn't destroy the i delta.Because it was on the 10V source.I could easily write the delta if resistance but I can not write now.

Comment: Please see the [Help Center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) for the information of what questions can be asked here and how.

Comment: I'm a new member of this site.I'm sorry but I need your help with this question.

Comment: That's not how this site works...we don't do your homework problems for you. Show us all of the work you have done so far; tell us as much as you can about your understanding of the problem; ask a specific question.

Comment: @SinanYalçın Homework needs an attempt at a solution or it is off topic

Comment: Yes.  Post your work and we will help.

Comment: Okay i changed it.

Comment: I've added i6 and ibgk while trying to solve the question.But the real form of the problem is at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You need another independent equation. Try writing a KCL equation at node 1 that relates \$i_\Delta\$ to the currents through the \$10\Omega\$ and \$30\Omega\$ resistors. Don't change your existing equation, just write a new one. You should be able to do the same substitutions for \$v_1\$ and \$v_3\$ so that you end up with a second equation with only \$i_\Delta\$ and \$v_2\$ as unknowns.

Hopefully, your two equations are independent and can be solved for both unknowns.

Comment: Ah okay.I created the equation for node 1. I combined the equations. And I found the result.Thank you.